# How to intentionally cause compile-time error in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

my goal is to create a `StepperComponent`. The stepper will need a `CounterService`.

The problem is, when we forget to add the `CounterService` in the `providers` key. The compiler will not throw error.

This prevent 100% confidence when migrating code, because the compiler will not throw error but when the user visit the page, it will be empty.

[source code](https://github.com/jasonrichdarmawan/angular-library-example)

=== How to use

projects/showcase/src/app/app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
// import { UiSdkComponent } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk';
import { ButtonModule } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk/button';
import { TranslatePipe } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk/i18n';
import { StepperModule } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk/stepper';
import { CounterService } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk/counter';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    // UiSdkComponent, 
    ButtonModule, 
    TranslatePipe,
    StepperModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    CounterService
  ],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'showcase';
}
```

=== The Stepper (part of @mycomp/ui-sdk library) and CounterService (part of @mycomp/ui-sdk library)

projects/mycomp/ui-sdk/stepper/src/stepper.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      StepperComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
      CommonModule,
      ButtonModule
    ],
    exports: [
      StepperComponent,
    ],
  })
  export class StepperModule {}
```

projects/mycomp/ui-sdk/stepper/src/stepper.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CounterService } from '@mycomp/ui-sdk/counter';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css'],
})
export class StepperComponent {
  constructor(public counterService: CounterService) {}
}
```

projects/mycomp/ui-sdk/counter/src/counter.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CounterService {
  count: number;

  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
  }

  increment() {
    this.count += 1;
  }

  decrement() {
    this.count -= 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to write tests. Only tests can guarantee that your code does what it is expected to do. Compilation only guarantees that your code is syntactically valid.

Comment: providers work on runtime only. what you are asking is not really possible